# state values are lately updated - React JS

Tags: reactjs, react-native

In my code, I'm trying to set a value to the particular state variables using event method in REACT JS. and also make some calculation for a Discounted price.
After Calculation, set the updated value to the state. But it should be updated lately whenever the next event occurs.

```
this.state = {
    isAddVariant: false,

    vendors: [],
    variant_price: '',
    variant_priceDiscount: '',
    variant_priceDiscounted: '',
    variant_unit: '',
    variants: [],
}
```

```
onVariantType = (e) => {

    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    })

    if (e.target.name === 'variant_price' || e.target.name === 'variant_priceDiscount') {
      let variant_priceDiscounted = this.state.variant_priceDiscount !== '' ? (this.state.variant_price - (this.state.variant_price * (this.state.variant_priceDiscount / 100))).toFixed(2) : this.state.variant_price
      this.setState({ variant_priceDiscounted })
    }

  }
```

// render function

```
<Typography variant="h7" color="inherit" style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
  Add Product Variants
</Typography>

<Grid container spacing={24}>
  {/* Input - Price */}
  <Grid item xs={2}>
    <TextField
      type={'number'}
      name={'variant_price'}
      value={nullToEmptyString(variant_price)}
      onChange={this.onVariantType}
      label={'Price'}
      placeholder={'Enter price in ₹'}
      required={true}
      margin={'dense'}
      autoComplete={'off'}
      fullWidth
    />
  </Grid>

  {/* Input - Unit */}
  <Grid item xs={2}>
    <TextField
      name={'variant_unit'}
      value={nullToEmptyString(variant_unit)}
      onChange={this.onVariantType}
      label={'Unit'}
      placeholder={'Enter unit (eg: kg)'}
      required={true}
      margin={'dense'}
      autoComplete={'off'}
      fullWidth
    />
  </Grid>

  {/* Input - Discount */}
  <Grid item xs={2}>
    <TextField
      type={'number'}
      name={'variant_priceDiscount'}
      value={nullToEmptyString(variant_priceDiscount)}
      onChange={this.onVariantType}
      label={'Discount'}
      placeholder={'Enter discount in %'}
      margin={'dense'}
      autoComplete={'off'}
      fullWidth
    />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={4}>
    <TextField
      type={'number'}
      name={'variant_priceDiscounted'}
      value={nullToEmptyString(variant_priceDiscounted)}
      label={'Discounted Price'}
      margin={'dense'}
      autoComplete={'off'}
      disabled
      fullWidth
    />
  </Grid>
  <Grid item xs={2}>
    {/* Button - Add */}
    <IconButton
      type={'add'}
      aria-label={'Add'}
      color={'primary'}
      onClick={this.onAddVariant}
    >
      <IconCheck />
    </IconButton>
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Expected behavior was Updated Discounted Value is calculated and displayed immediately.
Actual behaviour was the value lately updated Actual behavior image:
[image: Actual behavior image]

Comment: Hi Karthikeyan, check my solution and let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is `async`, and take time to update the state. `setState` takes a [callback](https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296), you can use it,

```
onVariantType = (e) => {
    let name = e.target.name; //store the name in a variable to use in callback
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }, () => { 
      if (name === 'variant_price' || name === 'variant_priceDiscount') {
        let variant_priceDiscounted = this.state.variant_priceDiscount !== '' ? (this.state.variant_price - (this.state.variant_price * (this.state.variant_priceDiscount / 100))).toFixed(2) : this.state.variant_price
        this.setState({ variant_priceDiscounted })
      }
    })
}
```

**Note:** We stored `e.target.name` in a `name` variable, because after `seState` execute's `e` gets nullifies. Read more about [`Synthetic events`](https://reactjs.org/docs/events.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply bro,,,, I used your solution....but it gives an error that is Parsing Error:Unexpected Token at the ()=>if() line.

Comment: @KarthikeyanP, check the updated answer, you need to wrap your if condition using `{}`.

Comment: ```onVariantType = (e) => {

    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value,
    }, {()=>if (e.target.name === 'variant_price' || e.target.name === 'variant_priceDiscount') {
      let variant_priceDiscounted = this.state.variant_priceDiscount !== '' ? (this.state.variant_price - (this.state.variant_price * (this.state.variant_priceDiscount / 100))).toFixed(2) : this.state.variant_price
      this.setState({ variant_priceDiscounted })
    }
  }      
  )
}```

Comment: You wrapped callback in `{}`, you just need to wrap `if` condition. Do what I did in answer, you can copy/paste.

Comment: That error was cleared bro..But it creates another runtime error...that was  TypeError:cannot read property 'name' of null....